# Regular Expression Search Replace all non leading tabs with single space Notepad++

Tags: regex, tabs

Regular Expressions have never been my strong suite, so I need some help here.  I have a text file and I want to replace any "embedded" tabs with a space and only one space for x occurrences of tabs, but leave any "leading" tabs alone.

So for a line that looks like this:

```
\t\t\tThis is a\t\ttest to see\thow things\t  will work.
```

would come out looking like this:

```
\t\t\tThis is a test to see how things will work.
```

So the only tabs left in the file would be at the beginning of any lines and there could be x number of tabs at the beginning of any line. Can anybody help me figure this one out?

I'm doing this with NotePad++ Search/Replace but I could use Visual Studio or some other tool if that would work better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find what:

```
(?<!\t)(?!^)\t+
```

The sequence of tabs `\t+` must not be preceded by a tab `(?<!\t)`, and also must not start from the beginning of a line `(?!^)`.

Replace with:

```
<space>
```

[**Demo on regex101**](http://www.regex101.com/r/aF1lQ1) (since Notepad++ also uses PCRE, I use `t` instead of tab for clarity)